# The average time complexity of linear search with weighted probability

Tags: algorithms

Given array of numbers $A[1..n]$. We search for element $x$  with linear search. Also we know that, element $x$ occurs in $A$ and probability of $x$ be in second half of the array is $3$ times of probability $x$ be in first half. What is the time complexity of linear search in average case?

Because of $x$ is in $A$, let $p$ be probability
$x$ be in first half, so
$$p+3p=1$$
so
$p=\frac{1}{4}.$

Also
I define Random variable $X$ as follow:

$$ X_i = \begin{cases} 
           \frac{1}{4}& ,1\leq i\leq \frac{n}{2} \\
          \frac{3}{4}& ,\frac{n}{2}<i\leq n
       \end{cases}
    $$
Let
$$X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n.$$
Now the expected of $X$ is as follow

$$ E[X]=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}X_i+\frac{3}{2n}\sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}+1}^{n} X_i $$
After solving above equality,
$E[X]=\frac{10n+8}{16}$.
But I think the answer is $\frac{5n}{8}$. What is my wrong?

Comment: Random variable defined with brace has only 2 different value, while in sum below it has $n$ different values.

Comment: @zkutch How I can fix it?

Comment: Write down separately values and probabilities for $X$. What you wrote are probabilities only.

Comment: @zkutch I fix it. Are you agree?

Comment: You need to write only values for random variable, not values times probabilities. This last is used in formula for expected value.

Answer (score 1):

We must assume $n$ even. As the average of an arithmetic progression is the average of the extreme members, the number of comparisons for the first half is $\dfrac{n+2}4$, and that for the second half is $\dfrac{3n+2}4$.

Then taking the weighted sum,

$$\dfrac{5n+4}8.$$

Anyway, we can spare the very last comparison because we know that the element is in the array and we must deduct $\dfrac3{4n}$.

Comment: Can you explain more about your idea? Thank you.

Comment: @jhjhb: which "idea", this is just a computation ? What is unclear ?

Comment: You are agree that my idea is correct?

Comment: But the i have doubt about that the answer is $\frac{3n}{4}$ or $\frac{5n}{8}$.

Comment: @jhjhb: IMO, neither. By the way, there is no $\frac{3n}4$.

Comment: So what is the answer?

Comment: @jhjhb: didn't I say it ?

Comment: If we _know_  that x is much more likely in the second half then we would do a linear search from the end to the star of the array, for about 3/8th n comparisons.

Comment: @gnasher729: quite right.